# Batch rename of methods using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automated-refactoring

I have a class with many (approximately 40) methods with names in `SCREAMING_CASE_LIKE_THIS`.

Is there a quick way, perhaps via the code analysis/inspections, to rename all of these to more idiomatic names in `camelCaseLikeThis`?

Comment: I'm not very sure about this so I'm not going to post it as an answer. But, there is a feature called structural search and replace in Intellij.  It might be able to do what you're talking about.  But, I could never figure out how to use it.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't look like SSR will do what I want in this case. I've been a bigger user of ReSharper for C# than IDEA over the last few years and there they have a way of specifying and enforcing naming conventions. I'm hoping to use the same for Java as well.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2007/01/syntax-highlighting-vs-naming-convention/  I don't know if there's a way to change the names in bulk though.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, with that enabled you can, from the popup, select _Fix all *** problems_ which takes you through each one in turn with a dialog. You can select a conformant name from the drop down. Definitely easier, but not as easy as it could be.

Comment: Hi Drew, did you use SSR for renaming your method? I'd like to rename my fieldnames but I'm having trouble. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Goot, sorry, this was a while back and I don't recall.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite a batch, but if you position the cursor above the first of the methods, start a macro recording then do:
control-alt-down
shift-f6
down-arrow
down-arrow
carriage-return

then stop the macro, you now have a macro that goes to the next method and renames it as you desired (camel case, without underscores). You can then assign that macro to a shortcut and repeat the appropriate number of times. I tried adding the last step to the macro as being a key combination which was not bound, then assigning that combination to the macro itself (so it was self calling) but I could not get that to work. Also tried creating another macro which invoked the first x times, but that would also not work for some reason.